# How to get the configured size of database file using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the configured size of each database file or the default size at the time of installation whatever file size was configured using T-SQL.

Comment: What you're asking for `... at the time of installation ...` is not possible after the file has grown as the size will have changed and SQL Server doesn't keep historical information about these things.

Comment: If the database was created on the server it's currently on, and not restored from another server, you could look at the size and autogrowth of the model database. This assumes it was created with all defaults. You may also be able to find some backup size information, with the additional caveat that you haven't pruned data from the necessary msdb tables. These are both probably long shots, depending on the age of the database/server.

Comment: @SeanGallardy..OHH..once db SIZE IS grown we cannot find its initial setup size. I wanted to check what was the initial size for one of the DB. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

This query can be helpful:

```
USE master;  
GO

ALTER DATABASE DBName   
MODIFY FILE  
(NAME = test1dat3, -- Logical File Name  
SIZE = 200MB);  
GO
```

For deafult use this:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [model] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'modeldev', SIZE = 6144KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [model] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'modellog', SIZE = 3072KB )
GO
```

Comment: This wont work as I don't want to modify the size instead need to find the default size when it was created. But anyways thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand, in this case you have to modify system database "model". Edit initial size of model database on value you want. In model database is saved template for create database.

Comment: I want to run a select query to get the output as what was the initial DB size value